# Listener refused the connection with the following error : ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Unable to connect to Local Oracle DB using SQLDeveloper.

[image]

I am able to connect through SQLPlus but get the above error in SQLDeveloper.

[image]
[image]

My connection details for SQLDeveloper :
[image]

Here are my *tnsnames.ora* and *listener.ora* files

**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ######.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ######.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

***######.com*** is the host-name of my PC.

I get the following message if I try to start the listener:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit :**

***Listener status*** (the part marked in yellow is my computer's name/host name)
[image]

Comment: Did you modify hostname  in the file listener.ora?

Comment: @DmitryDemin nope.

Comment: run `lsnrctl status`

Comment: @DmitryDemin I have added listener status as an edit. Kindly check it out.

Comment: run `sqlplus / as sydba` and type command  `alter system register` for register the instance with the listener and run again `lsnrctl status`

Answer (score 0):

try to set proper global name, find the current using:

```
select * from global_name;
```

and

```
alter database rename global_name to xe;
```

check further info using:

$>lsnrctl status

$>tnsping xe

Comment: or try switching to using the SID (xe) vs SERVICE